# How to integrate third party libraries in Angular library?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create an extension library for ngx-formly which basically depends nebular ui library for angular and ngx-formly/core.

But I am not sure how to integrate third party libraries inside an angular library.

I did some research and find that we should include third party libraries as peer dependencies.
But when I am testing it requires ui library and ngx-formly/core needs to be installed.

I have seen lot of articles on how to create a library but I didn't any find article or any explanation
About including a third party library in library.

If any one did please explain me how to do it(some code snippet will be helpful).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peer dependencies have the advantage of reducing final bundle size as the application doesn't need to install several versions of the third party library, bit it does mean the app has to install it. By making it a whitelisted direct dependency of your library you avoid that but instead lose that benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using node package manager (npm), if you'r library exists on node packeages you can easily install it by `npm i --save package-name` and `import`  it in any component or services. But if it is not possible and for example you wanna just have a costume `.js` library or thing like that you can place them under `assets` folder and use `angular.json` scripts part to import it inside your project and just use it.

Comment: I am want to use third party libraries in angular library but not in an angular project

Comment: OK, It's not OK that you modify the libraries code. So you have to create a new one based on the Fork of those libs.